# Issue With Apostrophe

Tags: sql-server-2000, apostrophe

I have a Proc that was coded in Dynamic SQl for one of my Application. It is using to search the Applicants with their last name. Right now it is searching applicants with either their first 2 digits of their last name or full last name. But i have a problem searching Applicants that have Apostrophe in their last name(Example O'Connor). If the client try to search applicant with O' or O'Connor it is throwing an error. They want to search every Applicant with or without Apostrophe in their last name. Please Help I tried everything, but its not working. Below is my search code that using in the Proc to pull applicants:

Add wildcards if necessary

```
if Rtrim(@FirstName) <> ''
begin 
  If(Len(@FirstName) < 30) and (CharIndex('%', @FirstName) = 0) and @FirstName != ''
         Set @FirstName = char(39) + @FirstName + '%' + char(39)
end 

if Rtrim(@LastName) <> ''
begin 
   If(Len(@LastName) < 60) and (CharIndex('%', @LastName) = 0) and @LastName != ''
     Set @LastName = Char(39) + @LastName + '%' + char(39)
end
```

Now build dinamically the filter base on input parameters

```
if Rtrim(@LastName) <> ''
 select @Where = @Where + ' and a.LastName like '+ Rtrim(@LastName)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the apostrophe in the input string (basically replace a single ' with two '') as you build your SQL string

You need to pay attention to this anywhere you choose to pass user input to a SQL server database as its a security issue (SQL Injection Attacks) c.f. [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

```
if Rtrim(@LastName) <> ''
 select @Where = @Where + ' and a.LastName like '+ Replace(Rtrim(@LastName),'''','''''') + ''
```

Comment: I'm getting the below Error when i execute the Proc. I Print the Select Statement from the Proc - I cannot put the whole statement here becasue of the limitation - below is what it print for the last name like:

Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'O'.

and a.LastName like ''O''REILLY%''

Comment: Are you replacing one apostrophe with two apostrophe ? Looks like you're replacing it with a double quote - which is not right

Comment: So here what i got when i Print the Current Code with out Adding code you gave me..

Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'REILLY'.
Server: Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Unclosed quotation mark before the character string ''.

 and a.LastName like 'O'REILLY%'

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to write the query to contain an alternate column to be used for filtering with the apostrophe/single quote replaced by any special character such as a #. This allows you to leave the original column intact in case you want to display it.

To do that in SQL Server, you could do something like this:

```
Select
    tbl.strName_Last,
    REPLACE(tblOrder.strName_Last, '''','#')) as StrLastNameForFilter
  ....
```

Then change your code to filter based on this alternate column, and in the user-provided filter string, replace the apostrophe/single quote with the special character.